# Fourier series representation review

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Calculate the Fourier series

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
& -6, && -\pi < x \le 0\\
& 6, && 0 < t < \pi
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

---

**My Work**

$a_n = \dfrac{1}{L}\int^L_{-L}f(t) \cos\left( \dfrac{n \pi t}{L} \right) dt$

$b_n = \dfrac{1}{L}\int^L_{-L}f(t) \sin\left( \dfrac{n \pi t}{L} \right) dt$

I got $a_n = 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$b_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \left[ \int^0_{-\pi} -6\sin(nt) dt + \int^\pi_0 6\sin(nt) dt \right]$

$= \dfrac{6}{\pi n} - \dfrac{6}{\pi n} \cdot \cos(-\pi n) - \dfrac{6}{\pi n} \cdot \cos(\pi n) + \dfrac{6}{\pi n}$

We can see that $\cos(-\pi n) = (-1)^n$ and $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$.

Therefore, we can simplify:

$= \dfrac{12}{\pi n} - \dfrac{6}{\pi n} \cdot (-1)^n - \dfrac{6}{\pi n}(-1)^n$

$= \dfrac{12}{\pi n} \left[ 1 - (-1)^n \right]$

$\left[ 1 - (-1)^n \right] = 0$ when $n$ is even.

Therefore, our Fourier series representation of $f(t)$ is

$f(t) = \dfrac{12}{\pi} \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1, odd} \dfrac{\left[ 1 - (-1)^n \right] \cdot \sin(nt)}{n}$

$= \dfrac{12}{\pi} \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1, odd} \dfrac{\left[ \sin(nt) - (-1)^n \cdot \sin(nt) \right]}{n}$

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my calculations and provide feedback.

Comment: Looks good. One simplification at the end: $1-(-1)^n=2$ for odd $n$, so you can just pulll that outside of the sum entirely.

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks for the response. In that case, we would have $f(t) = \dfrac{24}{\pi} \sum_{n = 1, odd}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(nt)}{n}$?

Comment: Correct. As a check, for $t=\pi/2$ one has (writing $n=2k+1$) $$f(\pi/2)=\frac{24}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}.$$ But this sum is the Leibniz formula for $\pi/4$, so $f(\pi/2)=6$ as it should.